# Inequality based on square

Tags: inequality

We need to find the range of $x$ for the following problem:

$$\frac{(x+6)(x-4)^2}{(x-6)(x+4)^2} + \frac{(x-6)(x+9)^2}{(x+6)(x-9)^2} < \frac{2x^2 + 72}{x^2 - 36}$$

They invlove the use of squares, which we have to avoid while solving inequalities.....And sadly, I cannot think of ways for trying this question. Can someone please give me hints/suggestions for solving? Formatting edits/suggestions are gladly welcomed! Question edits/suggestions are welcomed too!

EDITs:
So as discussed in the comments, I had got this for problem 1:
$$\frac{(x+6)(x-4)^2}{(x-6)(x+4)^2} + \frac{(x-6)(x+9)^2}{(x+6)(x-9)^2} < \frac{2x^2+72}{x^2-36}$$
which exapands to
$$\frac{(x+6)(x-4)^2(x+6)(x-9)^2}{(x-6)(x-4)^2(x+6)(x-9)^2} + \frac{(x-6)(x+9)^2(x-6)(x+4)^2}{(x+6)(x-9)^2(x-6)(x+4)^2} = \frac{2x^2+72}{x^2-36}$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{(x+6)(x-4)^2(x+6)(x-9)^2 + (x-6)(x+9)^2(x-6)(x+4)^2}{(x-6)(x+4)^2(x+6)(x-9)^2} = \frac{2x^2+72}{x^2-36}$$
and right now, I am stuck. I don't dare to open up that numerator (I have no guts in front of those brackets). There has to be a much elegant and simple looking solution than this brute-force.....But the problem is.....I can't find it! Anyone who would like to show some sympathy on me after this :(

Comment: "They invlove the use of square roots and squares, which we have to avoid while solving inequalities" : What does this mean?

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework.  What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Comment: In problem (1), what happens when you multiply everything out?  Please show your work.

Comment: Going forward with your future MathSE questions, in a similar situation, please post the problems as separate questions.  In general, there should be one Math problem presented for each posted question.

Comment: @user I meant that in general we tend to eliminate square roots and squares first in an inequality, to make it easier to comprehend and all......

Comment: @user thank you for your suggestions, i clearly understand i should post out anything that i have tried so that time is not wasted. basically i just used brute force and tried to simplify all those terms but in the end it was too overwhelming so i just stopped going further. there has to be some better approach than just brute force......

Comment: Are you saying that in problem (1), you have already attempted to 
manipulate the three fractions so that they each have the common denominator of 
$$(x-6) \times (x+6) \times (x+4)^2 \times (x-9)^2 ~?$$ 
If so, what was the result?

Comment: @user , yes, i did attempt (i wont deny that) but there are a few reasons why i did not mention it at the first place - 1) I am not happy with what I got, a long chain of terms it feels as if i have made a new polymer! (2) the place where i did all this "rough" requires extensive amounts of glue as every single page comes off that notebook (3) this is again, not a very efficient thing to do and chances of getting it incorrect is hugeeee, also i donot feel like it is even possible to solve since i have already encountered fourth degree terms on the way

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "...requires extensive amounts of glue".  You simply proofread/organize your work, and then type it directly into the posting via [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Also, often, even when there is a more elegant approach, the brute force method will reveal the corresponding simplifications.  That is, you may wish to double check whether arithmetic errors have prevented you from finding a simplification.  Personally, while there may be a more elegant approach, I am unsure why you would feel that a more elegant approach must exist.

Comment: @user I am sorry for any incovience caused....i have re-edited the question now.....expanding the brackets does help simplifying a lot of things and sometimes it also reveals what the question wants! sadly, i have almost lost hope in this :(

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by _'the range of $x$ for the following problem'_. Are you interested in the domain, i.e. a set of $x$-es for which the inequality makes _sense_ (aka it is _defined_)? Or rather in the set of $x$-es which _satisfy_ the inequality (values, for which it is _true_)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Some thoughts**:

Let $u = \frac{x + 6}{x - 6}$.
We have $x = \frac{6(u + 1)}{u - 1}$.
We have
$$\frac{x-4}{x+4} = \frac{u + 5}{5u + 1}, \quad \frac{x + 9}{x - 9} = \frac{5u - 1}{5 - u},
\quad \frac{2x^2 + 72}{x^2 - 36}
= \frac{(x+6)^2 + (x-6)^2}{(x - 6)(x + 6)} = u + \frac{1}{u}.$$

The inequality is written as
$$\frac{u(u+5)^2}{(5u+1)^2}
+ \frac{(5u-1)^2}{u(5-u)^2} < u + \frac{1}{u}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{u}\left(\frac{(5u-1)^2}{(5-u)^2} - 1\right) < u \left(1 - \frac{(u+5)^2}{(5u+1)^2}\right)$$
or
$$\frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{24(u^2 - 1)}{(5-u)^2} < u \cdot \frac{24(u^2 - 1)}{(5u+1)^2}$$
or
$$24(u^2 - 1)\left(\frac{u}{(5u+1)^2} - \frac{1}{u(5-u)^2}\right) > 0$$
or
$$\frac{24 (u + 1)u(u-1)(u^2 + 1)(u^2 - 10u - 1)}{(5u+1)^2(5-u)^2u^2} > 0$$
or
$$\frac{24(u^2 + 1)}{(5u+1)^2(5-u)^2u^2}
 (u + 1)(u - 5 + \sqrt{26})u(u-1)(u - 5 - \sqrt{26}) > 0.$$

Comment: we are supposed to deduce that $u^2 + 1$ is always positive and remove all the squares in the denominator with the conditions  $u \neq \frac{-1}{5} , 5 , 0$ ??

Comment: @CuckooBeats Alternatively, you can insert $u = (x+6)/(x-6)$ back to the last inequality. You will get something like $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)(x-e) > 0$. For example, $(x+3)(x+1)(x-1) > 0$, the solution is $(-3, -1)\cup (1, \infty)$. But don't forget the zeros of the denominator, as you pointed out.

Comment: well this indeed was a good solution, but can we substitute better variables to the inequality? i just want to know.....although this might be the best known solution for this question, can we still try it out?

Comment: @CuckooBeats Do you mean that first the last inequality has solution $u \in (-1, -1/5)\cup (-1/5, 5 - \sqrt{26})\cup (0, 1) \cup (5+\sqrt{26}, \infty)$, then convert this solution into $x$?

Comment: no i meant the whole question......like you did $u = \frac{x+6}{x-6}$, can there be a better substitution as the solution seems lengthier, isn't it? also it would be better to first replace the value of $u$ in your last inequality and then simplify and solve for $x$.....

Comment: @CuckooBeats OK. Yes, it is simpler to replace $u$ with $x$.

Comment: hello, i have added my solution to the problem, the trick i found useful was $2a^2 +2b^2 = (a+b)^2+(a-b)^2$

Comment: @CuckooBeats It is the same as mine? You may give a complete detailed solution with final answer as an accepted answer.

Comment: oh definetly it is going to come the same, but i feel mine a bit more comfortable than yours, no offence, but it seems we need to work out more in your approach, although i had never thought the same earlier, thanks!

Comment: @CuckooBeats Your $\frac{(x+6)}{(x-6)}\cdot\left[\frac{(x-4)^2}{(x+4)^2}-1\right]+\frac{(x-6)}{(x+6)}\cdot\left[\frac{(x+9)^2}{(x-9)^2}-1\right] < 0$ is the same as my $\frac{1}{u}\left(\frac{(5u-1)^2}{(5-u)^2} - 1\right) < u \left(1 - \frac{(u+5)^2}{(5u+1)^2}\right)$. So basically the same thing.

Comment: oh yess, i did not notice that step, basically we could replace $u$ back and get the same equation.......actually i would want to do the same thing as yours when nothing strikes at my head.....

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to everyone who took much time and helped me to solve the questions. Here's the solution to the first problem after a lot of research and hints from teachers. Note that this solution is analogus to @RiverLi 's solution....

We can simplify $2x^2 + 72$ as $$2\cdot x^2 + 2\cdot6^2 + 2\cdot x\cdot6 - 2\cdot x\cdot6$$
or $$(x+6)^2 + (x-6)^2$$
now, we can easily simplify the RHS
$$\frac{2x^2+72}{x^2-36} = \frac{(x+6)^2+(x-6)^2}{(x+6)(x-6)} = \frac{(x+6)}{(x-6)}+\frac{(x-6)}{(x+6)}$$
sweet! plugging this outcome in the original question:
$$\frac{(x+6)(x-4)^2}{(x-6)(x+4)^2} + \frac{(x-6)(x+9)^2}{(x+6)(x-9)^2} < \frac{(x+6)}{(x-6)}+\frac{(x-6)}{(x+6)}$$
or
$$\frac{(x+6)}{(x-6)}\cdot\left[\frac{(x-4)^2}{(x+4)^2}-1\right]+\frac{(x-6)}{(x+6)}\cdot\left[\frac{(x+9)^2}{(x-9)^2}-1\right] < 0$$
after that, you can easily simplify and go on to find the range of $x$. Make sure to not encounter fourth degree polynomials and instead eliminate terms like squares, $x^2 + 36$ as they are never negative. Also make sure to intersect the domain of $x$ while cancelling terms in the denominator.
here's the working after this:

> $\frac{(x+6)}{(x-6)}\cdot\left[\frac{((x-4)+(x+4))((x-4)-(x+4))}{(x+4)^2}\right]+\frac{(x-6)}{(x+6)}\cdot\left[\frac{((x+9)+(x-9))((x+9)-(x-9))}{(x-9)^2}-1\right] < 0$

or

> $\frac{(x+6)}{(x-6)}\cdot\left[\frac{(2x)(-8)}{(x+4)^2}\right]+\frac{(x-6)}{(x+6)}\cdot\left[\frac{(2x)(18)}{(x-9)^2}\right] < 0$

cancel $4$ both sides, we get

> $\frac{9x(x-6)}{(x+6)(x-9)^2} - \frac{4x(x+6)}{(x-6)(x+4)^2} < 0$

this simplied result gives me eternal satisfaction I needed for this question XD

simplifying further, we get

> $x\cdot\left[\frac{9(x-6)^2(x+4)^2 - 4(x+6)^2(x-9)^2}{(x+6)(x-6)(x+4)^2(x-9)^2}\right] < 0$

or

> $x\cdot\left[\frac{(3x^2-6x-72)^2 - (2x^2-6x-108)^2}{(x+6)(x-6)(x+4)^2(x-9)^2}\right] < 0$

sweet!

> $\frac{(5x^2-12x-180)(x^2+36)}{(x+6)(x-6)(x+4)^2(x-9)^2} < 0$

now,

> $5x^2-12x-180$ has no integer roots, so we shall apply the quadractic formula to find the roots of x. Don't lose hopes though as we can now freely eliminate x^2 + 36 , (x+4)^2 . (x-9)^2 (they are never negative :D)

this simplifies the equation to

> $\frac{(5x^2-12x-180)}{(x+6)(x-6)} < 0$

too many spoilers right? i am providing the solution now :D

domain:
$$x \in (-\infty , -4) \cup (-4 , 9) \cup (9 , \infty)$$

range:
$$x \in (-\infty , -6) \cup \left(\frac{12 - \sqrt{3744}}{10} , 0\right)\cup \left(6 , \frac{12 + \sqrt{3744}}{10}\right)$$

intersecting the domain and the range, the finalllll answerrrrr:
$$x \in (-\infty , -6) \cup \left(\frac{12 - \sqrt{3744}}{10} , -4\right) \cup (-4 , 0) \cup \left(6 , \frac{12 + \sqrt{3744}}{10}\right)$$

> eternal satisfaction reached

Comment: It is nice. (+1). Actually, now you can accept your answer.

Comment: @river its fine.....your solution seems more intuitive to find